# Inserting Multiple values of int type into one column

Tags: sql-server

Hey so I am new to sql and am building an inventory management system. So for the database i am getting stuck at this point where I need to insert the various user id's to different Teams in the company, hence my problem arises when I am trying to assign multiple int values to a particular team.The DB is made in a manner where it requires a TeamId and the corresponding UserId's to go with it.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or What have you tried?

Comment: Can you paste your table structure and query you are firing?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that I am trying to import these values from an excel sheet..
The query i used is --insert into Tbl_Inventory_T_TeamUsers (TeamId,UserId) select * from dbo.TUserX$
and the error message it throws is --Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,19' to data type int.

Comment: So when you say multiple int values, did you mean they are comma separated? Do you want to insert those as they coming from excel or you want to insert those as different rows like 1 and 19?

Comment: 1,19 is not an integer. It is a varchar.

Comment: Yes exactly i currently have them comma separated, and yes i want to insert them as they are in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID INT)

-- For 2008 and higher

INSERT INTO @temp (ID)
VALUES (1), (2), (3)

-- For 2005 and higher

INSERT INTO @temp (ID)
SELECT ID
FROM (
    SELECT ID = 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6
) t

SELECT * 
FROM @temp
```

**Update (comment @Sivakumar: *"1,19 is not an integer. It is a varchar."*):**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (txt varchar(500))

INSERT INTO @temp (txt)
VALUES ('1,19'), ('2,18')

SELECT t.c.value('.', 'INT')
FROM (
    SELECT txml = CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(txt, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
    FROM @temp
) a
CROSS APPLY txml.nodes('/t') AS t(c)
```

Comment: Please don't down-vote, because I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: As said before yes it is a one to many relationship between the team and TeamUsers table.. I have already created the entire design of the DB and now am just trying to populate it. 
The TeamUsers table has 4 columns; Id(PK)-int,TeamId-Datatype is int null not allowed, UserId -Datatype is int null not allowed 
So to put it simple I just want to know how to put multiple int values into UserId for each TeamId

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a one-to-many relationship: a Team can have zero or more Users.

So create a foreign key column in User that references the Team primary key.

Something like this (check my syntax):

```
create table team (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    primary key(id);
);

create table user (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    tid int,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key tid references(team);
);

select * 
from team t
join user u
on t.id = u.tid;
```